# Difference between "meeting" and "meet up"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Is this sentence correct?

> Can we skip the *meet up* this week?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22meet+up%22 *meet up* (informal, Origin: 2000-05) = *meeting* (more formal, also found in informal use)

Comment: @mplungjan *meet up* is also a noun.

Comment: Hmm, then it would be meetup or meet-up - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meet-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hyphen or no space

> Can we skip the meetup/meet-up this week

but I would prefer

> Can we skip the meeting this week and meet up next week

So a meetup/meet-up or to meet up

Comment: I would suggest you need a hyphen (or no space) when *it's a noun*, but I would write ***meet up*** as a phrasal *verb* (with a space).

Comment: I wouldn't use *meet up* as a verb at all. What's wrong with just *meet*?

Comment: It does sound more like an "Arranged informal meeting" that just meet. IF we meet, we do not have to talk at all. Just walk or sit next to each other in silence.  If we have a meetup, we are going to discuss stuff